# Change work library to D drive for SAS EG 5.1

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Hi I don't have much space on my C drive so I'm looking to move my work library for SAS EG 5.1 over to a folder on my D drive. How could I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are using EG to work locally, you can change it in your sasv9.cfg file:

[image]

This is usually found in the SASFoundation/nls/en (or equivalent language) directory.

Another option (which avoids changing the config file) is to change the value of the TEMP environment variable.  Remember though that SAS is I/O heavy, and if the D drive is a remote network location you may suffer performance-wise..

Comment: You can also add `-work "d:\saslib"` to the command line that launches SAS.

Answer (score 2):

An option if you're unable to modify the Config file, is to define a `USER` libname:

```
libname user "d:\saslib\";
```

or similar.  That will become your default one-level libname (ie, if you say `data have;` that will now be stored in `user.have`, not `work.have`).  It doesn't override it if you have specified `work` explicitly, and it doesn't automatically clean up after itself, so be aware of these issues.